# Get XML body from accountingApi.getContactsForHttpResponse

Tags: java, xml, xero-api

I am doing some proof of concept tests for a future development with the xero java api.

I would like to get the XML response body of the HttpResponse.

Here is my code

```
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.ClientCredentialsTokenRequest;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.RefreshTokenRequest;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.BasicAuthentication;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.xero.api.ApiClient;
import com.xero.api.client.AccountingApi;
import com.xero.api.client.IdentityApi;
import com.xero.models.identity.Connection;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class XeroConnection {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    final String clientId = "Myid";
    final String clientSecret = "MySecret";
    final String TOKEN_SERVER_URL = "https://identity.xero.com/connect/token";
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
    private AccountingApi accountingApi;
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XeroConnection.class);

    private String jwt_token = "";
    private String access_token = "";
    private String refresh_token = "";
    private String expires_in_seconds = "";
    private String xero_tenant_id = "";

public XeroConnection (){
}

public void test() {
    ArrayList<String> scopeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    scopeList.add("accounting.settings");
    scopeList.add("accounting.transactions");
    scopeList.add("accounting.contacts");
    scopeList.add("accounting.journals.read");
    scopeList.add("accounting.reports.read");
    scopeList.add("accounting.attachments");

    try {
        TokenResponse tokenResponse =
        new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
            new GenericUrl(TOKEN_SERVER_URL))
            .setScopes(scopeList)
            .setClientAuthentication(
            new BasicAuthentication(clientId, clientSecret)).execute();
        System.out.println("Access token: " + tokenResponse.getAccessToken());
        ApiClient defaultIdentityClient = new ApiClient("https://api.xero.com", null, null, null, null);
        IdentityApi idApi = new IdentityApi(defaultIdentityClient);
        List<Connection> connection = idApi.getConnections(tokenResponse.getAccessToken(),null);

        jwt_token = tokenResponse.toPrettyString();
        access_token = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
        refresh_token = tokenResponse.getRefreshToken();
        expires_in_seconds = tokenResponse.getExpiresInSeconds().toString();
        xero_tenant_id = connection.get(0).getTenantId().toString();

        // Check expiration of token and refresh if necessary
        String accessToken = checkToken(access_token,refresh_token);

        // Init AccountingApi client
        ApiClient defaultClient = new ApiClient();

        // Get Singleton - instance of accounting client
        accountingApi = AccountingApi.getInstance(defaultClient);   


        // Get All Contacts
        HttpResponse contacts = accountingApi.getContactsForHttpResponse(accessToken,xero_tenant_id,null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        
        //contacts.getbody();



    }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

public String checkToken(String accessToken, String refreshToken) throws IOException {
    String currToken = null;

    try {
        DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(accessToken);

        if (jwt.getExpiresAt().getTime() > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug(
                        "------------------ Refresh Token : NOT NEEDED - return current token -------------------");
            }
            currToken = accessToken;
        } else {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("------------------ Refresh Token : BEGIN -------------------");
            }
            try {
                TokenResponse tokenResponse = new RefreshTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
                        new GenericUrl(TOKEN_SERVER_URL), refreshToken)
                        .setClientAuthentication(new BasicAuthentication(this.clientId, this.clientSecret))
                        .execute();
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("------------------ Refresh Token : SUCCESS -------------------");
                }

                // DEMO PURPOSE ONLY - You'll need to implement your own token storage solution
                jwt_token = tokenResponse.toPrettyString();
                access_token = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
                refresh_token = tokenResponse.getRefreshToken();
                expires_in_seconds = tokenResponse.getExpiresInSeconds().toString();

                currToken = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
            } catch (TokenResponseException e) {
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("------------------ Refresh Token : EXCEPTION -------------------");
                }
                if (e.getDetails() != null) {
                    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        logger.debug("Error: " + e.getDetails().getError());
                    }
                    if (e.getDetails().getErrorDescription() != null) {
                        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                            logger.debug(e.getDetails().getErrorDescription());
                        }
                    }
                    if (e.getDetails().getErrorUri() != null) {

                        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                            logger.debug(e.getDetails().getErrorUri());
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        logger.debug("------------------ Refresh Token : EXCEPTION -------------------");
                        logger.debug(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (JWTDecodeException exception) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("------------------ Refresh Token : INVALID TOKEN -------------------");
            logger.debug(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return currToken;
}
}
```

Almost everything is taken from the Xero Java custom connections Starter.
https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-java-custom-connections-starter

I can see that the Java API is using custom classes to load the informatrion from xero, but I would like to the also get the response body in XML format

I am trying to get something in the line of

```
contacts.getbody();
```

Or is there any better way of getting the raw XML body?

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: I have updated the post with more information, hope that is better this way. Thanks for your feedback.